# Testing unit with skip_before_action does not unset after using TDD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, tdd, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using Rails 5.2 and doing some testing. I am trying my unit testing with `ActionController::TestCase` and found that `@controller.class.skip_before_action :verify_user` does not reset the controller automatically before going to the next test unit method.

Now because rails tests are randomized at every run, certain unit fails sometimes and not other times. I figured it was expecting HTTP 401 but I got 200. Cause the controller ignored to `before_action :verify_user`.

I could set `@controller.class.before_action :verify_user` at end of every unit (and it works!) but should it not be the rep of testing sys to reset context before every run?

Giving a snip of my code:

```
class ApiSiteMetricsTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests Api::SiteMetricsController

  def test_1_index
    @controller.class.skip_before_action :verify_user,raise: false

    get "index",  params:{ 
        "format"=>"json",
        "site_metric_value"=>{
            "site_metric_id"=>2403, 
            "date_acquired"=>"2018-03-14T01:44:00+05:30", 
            "site_id"=>3840, 
            "lab_device_details"=>"", 
            "comment"=>"", 
            "sender_affiliation"=>"", 
            "float_value"=>""
        }
    }
    assert_response :success
    File.open("#{Rails.root}/del.html", "wb") { |f| f.write(@response.body) }        
    #Do I have to do this o every test?
    #@controller.class.before_action :verify_user
  end
  ...
```

Comment: don't you have some configuration to enable the context reset after each test ? with rspec it is done with `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` in spec_helper.rb.
Also with rspec you have before(:each) and after(:each) callback to put your skip and before_action in , avoiding to paste it into each test manually

Comment: `config.use_transactional_fixtures` is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right that each test should reset the state of the system after running. Tests should should be entirely independent - which is precisely why they are run in a random order (by default).

For most things - such as database transactions - the test framework can handle this for you. But there are infinitely other ways that you could alter the environment; the test framework cannot *always* cover your back.

For example, what if your test changes an `ENV` variable? Or calls [`Timecop.freeze`](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop)? Or adds a database record *via a second database connection*? Or sets a global variable? ...

Sometimes, you need to reset the state manually!

In this case, I would do:

```
class ApiSiteMetricsTest < ActionController::TestCase
  tests Api::SiteMetricsController

  def test_1_index
    @controller.class.skip_before_action :verify_user,raise: false

    # ...

    ensure

    @controller.class.before_action :verify_user
  end
end
```

The `ensure` is there so that even if this test fails, the state should be reset regardless - therefore not affecting whether or not *other* tests fail.

In some cases, you may find it convenient to use `MiniTest`'s `setup` and `teardown` methods to provide this functionality. (Equivalent to the `before` and `after` hooks in `rspec`).

Comment: As an alternative, you could just `stub` the `verify_user` method in this test, rather than changing the class' definition.

Comment: Is there no way to just reset `@controller.class` definition? like calling `@controller = Api::PeopleController.new` in `setup` should have reloaded the class def